# Help with Integration by Trigonometric Substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

So, I have this problem:
$$
\int \frac{\sqrt{36x^{2}-49}}{x^{3}}dx, x>\frac{7}{6}
$$
We're supposed to use Trigonometric Substitution to solve it. I've used integration by parts to get to this point:
$$
\int \frac{\sqrt{36x^{2}-49}}{x^{3}}dx = -\frac{\sqrt{36x^{2}-49}}{2x^{2}}+\int\frac{18}{x\sqrt{36x^{2}-49}}dx
$$
However, I have no clue what to do after this. I used an online calculator and it said that the right integral ends up being $\frac{7}{6}sec(u)$ or something because of that one trig identity, but I would like to know why that is, so I can understand problems like this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the surd like $\sqrt{a^2x^2-b^2}$, we usually try the substitution
$$
x=\frac{b}{a} \sec \theta \Rightarrow  \sqrt{a^2x^2-b^2}=b\tan \theta \textrm{ and } dx=\frac ba\sec \theta\tan \theta d\theta
$$
to express the integral in terms of trigonometric functions.
\begin{aligned}
J & =\int \frac{7 \tan \theta}{\left(\frac{7}{6}\right)^3 \sec ^3 \theta} \cdot \frac{7}{6} \sec \theta \tan \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{36}{7} \int \frac{\tan ^2 \theta}{\sec ^2 \theta} d \theta \\
& =\frac{36}{7} \int \sin ^2 \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{36}{7} \int \frac{1-\cos 2 \theta}{2} d \theta \\
& =\frac{18}{7}\left(\theta-\frac{\sin 2 \theta}{2}\right)+C \\
& = \frac{18}{7} \sec ^{-1} \frac{6 x}{7}-\frac{\sqrt{36 x^2-49}}{2 x^2}+C\end{aligned}

Comment: Does that substitution work for any trig function or only sec?

Comment: For the surd like $\sqrt{a^2x^2+b^2}$, let $x=\frac{b}{a} \tan \theta$; For the surd like $\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2}$, let $x=\frac{a}{b} \sin \theta$;